# Left side of split view is blank after switching screens and changing from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

This is a really strange issue I have not been able to narrow down.

The left side of a split view screen goes black under certain conditions.  These are,

1. The first, and the most odd, is that the screen must initially be loaded in portrait mode.  If its loaded in landscape I can't reproduce this issue.
2. in portrait mode (where the left side of the split view is hidden) you hit a button to display the popover of the left view, then dismiss it.
3. go to the next screen in the navigation.
4. change to landscape
5. go back to the split view screen

and poof, the left side of the split view is black.  Like the view was never loaded.

initially my thoughts were that this was a memory leak issue, having to do with the popover not being de-allocated correctly.

However, the fact the app must start in portrait mode really confuses me.  Even if i start in landscape, then move to portrait for step 1 and go through the process, it all works fine.  Even through multiple iterations of these steps, it never triggers the blank screen.

I would assume I should post code but I'm so lost as to what the issue could be, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard?

Comment: no.  The problem is the fact the split view is inside a tab view.  This is marked in apple docs as incompatible and the only solution is to build a custom split view